# Manage several versions of a same route with api-platform

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I use Symfony and api-platform to build my apis.

I would like to manage two versions of the same route. For example:
**path_url/v1/myroute** and **path_url/v2/myroute**

Is it possible to do that with api-platform? (I suppose the answer is YES but I did not found how in the documentation)

Moreover, how to manage two versions of the Swagger? For the moment I have one version of the Swagger:

[image]

How to see the different versions and allow the users to choose between V1 and V2?

Comment: My initial thought is to componentize the api into a separate repo, tag it for `v1` and `v2` using semver, then in your app import each separated api component (with it's own configuration) and provide routing to each one. To allow switching you would probably need something custom. Knowing Dunglas though, there's probably a way.

Comment: thanks Jared. It is a little too complicated for me (I am a beginner with symfony/API platform). I found another solution, see below. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Here what I found.

In my entities I added the "routePrefix annotation" :

[image]

And here :

[image]

Like that my swagger is now :

[image]

It not exactly what I was looking for but it's ok with me !

Answer (score 0):

You can as well define the route prefix globally in api_platform.yaml. See image link below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9p2B.png)

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).